# Why if I include an image, the first page of my document start without content?

Tags: graphics, books, emptypage

If I compile my code the document start from the second page, but I need that start from the firs ones.

when I eliminate the image that Im using the document star normally, But I need both, the image and start from the first page.

This is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{pgf,tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%     \DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}

\title{Propuesta de Investigación\\Analisis de bifurcaciónes de Codimensión-2 en un Modelo de Desarrollo sostenible\vspace{5cm}\\} \author{Juan Pablo Muñoz Diaz\\} \date{\today} \begin{document}

\begin{center} \begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
    \centering
    %Degree
    {\Large Propuesta de Investigación remitida para aprobar el titulo de Maestría en Ciencias Matemática Aplicada\par}
    \vspace{1cm} %University logo
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{logounal.png}\\ %   \rule{0.4\linewidth}{0.15\linewidth}\par
    \vspace{3cm} %Thesis title
    {\uppercase{\bf{TITULO}\vspace{.1cm}\\ 
    \Large ANALISIS DE BIFURCACIONES DE CODIMENSIÓN-2, BT Y GH EN UN MODELO DE DESARROLLO SOSTENIBLE\par}}
    \vspace{3cm} %Author's name

    {Tutor\\\Large Gerar Olivar Tost\par}
    \vspace{0.5cm}    {Estudiante\\ \Large Juan Pablo Muñoz Diaz\par}
    \vspace{3cm}

%Date
    {\Large Noviembre de 2016 } 
\end{minipage} 
\end{center} 
\clearpage


\end{document}
```

Comment: Most likely, the image is too tall. Your log probably says something about overfull hbox. That message indicates how much the image should be reduced in size.

Comment: The explicit `\vspace`s alone sum up to about 16cm. Then you have a three-line description of the type of thesis and a five-line title, in huge letters. There is an `Overfull \vbox` warning in your log file. Reduce the numbers in the `\vspace` commands until this warning goes away.